# Selecting only one result from a set

Tags: sql, select

I have a user table (id,group) and need to select 1 if a user is not a member of a group. A Member can be a member of multiple groups so there may be more than one record for each ID(not unique)

I can only return one(pass/fail) value and I need to basically check all of the records to see if the user is a member of 'admin'. If the are a member of 'admin' i need the statement to fail. If none of the user's groups is admin then I need it to pass. I have tried a couple of different ways but I dont know if I am on the correct path.

```
SELECT 1 
FROM GRP
WHERE USER = 'name'
AND GROUP NOT IN ('ADMIN')

SELECT 0 
FROM GRP
WHERE USER = 'name'
AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM GRP
        WHERE USER = 'name'
        AND GROUP NOT IN ('ADMIN')
    )
```

EDIT = How I solved my problem

```
SELECT 1
FROM GRP
WHERE 'name' NOT IN
    (
        select USER
        from GRP
        group by USER
        having sum(case when GROUP = 'ADMIN' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and then check whether the admin group is in the list in the `having` clause:

```
select user
from grp
group by user
having sum(case when group = 'ADMIN' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The above returns all users.  You can add the `where` clause for a particular user if you like.

If you want a flag for the user, instead of filtering out the ones in the admin group:

```
select user, max(case when group = 'ADMIN' then 1 else 0 end) as AdminFlag
from grp
group by user;
```

EDIT:

If you want a 0 or 1 flag for a given user:

```
select max(case when group = 'ADMIN' then 1 else 0 end) as IsInAdminFlag
from grp
where user = 'name';
```

Comment: Using your first example I can see i am getting close. How would I check to see if a user is in the returned result and then return a 1 if they are?

Comment: I got it working using a round about what of what you did. I updated my question to show how it is currently working. But thanks for your answer you were a big help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 AS COL
FROM GRP
WHERE USER = 'name'
AND GROUP NOT IN ('ADMIN')
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS COL
FROM GRP
WHERE USER = 'name'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM GRP
    WHERE USER = 'name'
    AND GROUP NOT IN ('ADMIN')
)
```

Comment: I tried this out and it still returns the rows that are not 'ADMIN'. I need to somehow return a 0 if any of the records for a user have 'ADMIN' and return a 1 if none of them do. 

for example, my test acccount is a member of 5 groups, this returns 4 records(leaving out the sysadmin record)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer you could use that will give you a list of all users and their states. Just add filter by name.

```
select
  user,
  max(case when group = 'admin' then 1 else 0 end) state
from
  GRP
where
  user = 'my_name'
group by
  user
```